# dmesg spamming "Power-on or device reset occurred"

Tags: hard-drive, io, controller, raid-controller, dmesg

So I have a DELL R730xd Server with 24 SSDs on a PERC H730P Mini controller in HBA mode. All 24 drives are in one big ZFS Raid-Z2 pool.

I have noticed that dmesg gets spammed with a lot of these messages for basically all disks:

```
...
[Tue Mar 12 03:38:50 2024] sd 0:0:8:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:39:58 2024] sd 0:0:3:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:39:58 2024] sd 0:0:19:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:41:05 2024] sd 0:0:3:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:42:13 2024] sd 0:0:11:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:42:13 2024] sd 0:0:13:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:43:21 2024] sd 0:0:8:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:44:29 2024] sd 0:0:2:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:45:34 2024] sd 0:0:3:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:46:45 2024] sd 0:0:9:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:47:52 2024] sd 0:0:3:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:47:52 2024] sd 0:0:18:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:48:00 2024] sd 0:0:9:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:49:09 2024] sd 0:0:6:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:50:16 2024] sd 0:0:13:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:51:21 2024] sd 0:0:15:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:52:27 2024] sd 0:0:19:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:53:55 2024] sd 0:0:22:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:53:55 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:54:04 2024] sd 0:0:9:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:55:09 2024] sd 0:0:9:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:56:13 2024] sd 0:0:9:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Tue Mar 12 03:57:21 2024] sd 0:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
...
```

I don't get any other errors other than these and the disks themselves are healthy and don't report any errors.

My observations so far point towards coinciding disk intensive tasks like VM backups or zfs scrubbing. But disk intensive tasks shouldn't change the power state (on/off) of a hard disk should they?
How do I get to know the root cause for this problem?